# OpenLayers 4 - Ionic 2 not displaying the map after changing page even if the map is loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm making an application that has 2 page and on each of them, there is a map. The problem is when starting the application, a map is displayed. But after that I go to the second page, nothing is there even if the object map is created.
And if I come back to the first page, there is also nothing even if the first time, that worked. (There is only a little dark gray rectangle on the upper left side of the page that appeared).

The creation of the map is the same on the 2 pages.

Thank you for your help !

**page1.ts**

```
import { Component , ViewChild, Renderer, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MapProvider } from '../../providers/map-provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html'
})
export class Page1 {
  @ViewChild('map') map: ElementRef;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,platform: Platform, public renderer: Renderer, public mapService: MapProvider) { }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
      this.map = this.mapService.loadMap(this.map);
      console.log(this.map);
  }
}
```

Page 2 is the same

**page1.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <div id="map" #map class="map" cache-view="false">
      <button class="geolocateButton" color="danger" ion-button icon-only (click)="geolocate()">
          <ion-icon name="locate"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**Map-provider.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import * as ol from 'openlayers';

@Injectable()
export class MapProvider {

  constructor() {}

  loadMap(map){
    var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
      })
    });
    return map;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about wrapping it in a setTimeout?

```
setTimeout(() => {
         this.loadMap(map);
       }, 500);
```